# Which data structure do you suggest for handling this data?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a grid network with a number nodes with (x,y) coordinates, and I have a couple of individuals that visit these nodes in the network. For instance, individual 1 visits nodes `(1,3)`, `(4,5)`, `(8,9)` and individual 2 visits `(4,3)`, `(2,5)`.

I need to access these nodes for each individual (let say in a for loop for all individuals) but I do not know the best way of doing it in python.

Comment: A `class Individual` with a list of `nodes`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class called Individual to hold all the relevant information for that individual. You can then put those Individual objects in a list or whatever data structure you want.

```
class Individual:
    def __init__(self, visited):
        self.visited = visited  # type: list[tuple]

    def add_visit(self, node):
        self.visited.append(node)


individuals = [
    Individual([(1, 3), (4, 5), (8, 9)]), 
    Individual([(4, 3), (2, 5)])
]

for individual in individuals:
    pass  # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Others suggest a class for this task, but I think you would be better off with just a normal dictionary (`dict`), or `defaultdict`. No need to create a class for a thing that has no methods and only contains a list of nodes, especially when python has such a fantastic arsenal of containers.

Solution with a dict in Python 3:

```
individuals = {}
individuals["1"] = [(1, 3), (4, 5), (8, 9)]
individuals["2"] = [(4, 3), (2, 5)]

for ind, node in individuals.items():
    print(ind, node)

individuals["2"].append((6, 7))
```

Comment: You say *"no need to create a class"* as if creating a class was expensive. I'd say there is no need to create dictionary where a class is more logical.

Comment: I say it as not expensive, but a logical one. But it is an argument about paradigms that is ultimately about preference. I prefer to use containers when operating with data that will not have any sensible methods and is just that: data. A class solution presented here is no more than a wrapper over a list. And I suspect that there will be some computations done with the data. You can rarely outperform the python builtins in efficiency with calculations.Also, individuals["1"][i] vs individuals[0].visited[i]. But like I said, it is a paradigm preference thing and there are no right answers.

Comment: You are free to express your argument about why "class is more logical", since I think quite the opposite :P

Comment: Of course it is a about preference. It just sounded like you had other motives against classes. Anyway, I don't use dict if there is no mapping (key->value) involved in the problem and I avoid too much nesting (e.g. lists of lists of dicts of sets of  tuples), because such code is not readable. When you encounter an instance of `Individual`, you know what it is, but a dict mapping strings to lists of tuples is could be anything.

Comment: True enough. Depends definitely on the use case. If the individuals do not need to be accessed by a key and just iterated over, it could very well be even a list of list of tuples. You are right, it might become unclear at some point, and I of course take readable code over slightly better performing at any time. If I would use a class, I would probably subclass `list`, so that I would get the best of both worlds. Then I could know the instance when I encounter it, but also have the convenience of builtins.